# NSTableView setRowSizeStyle

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I guess setRowSizeStyle is supposed to change the font size of my NSTableView, and make everything smaller.

Is this correct ?
- If so, of you know an alternative method for Leopard ? (prev OSX 10.7)

- If it is not correct, what could I use instead ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, `setRowSizeStyle` method is used to define the size of the rows in the table view. for font size refer https://stackoverflow.com/q/8257631/944634.