# Is there an easy way to change the font size for a NSTableView?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Is there an easy way to change the font size for a NSTableView ?

I've tried this"

```
 - (void)drawRect:(NSRect)r {

    [self setFont:[NSFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:7]];
    [self reloadData];
            [super drawRect:r];
 }
```

I'm sure drawRect is invoked but it doesn't work

I've also tried this:

```
NSArray *columns = [self tableColumns];
        for (id column in columns) {
            id cell = [column dataCell];
            [cell setFont: [NSFont fontWithName: @"Geneva" size:22.0] ];
            //[column setDataCell:cell]; tried both with and without

        }
        [self reloadData];
```

before to print the table. 
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create

```
IBOutlet NSTableColumn *mycolumn;
```

For each column. then use `dataCell:` method which will returns the `NSCell` object then apply `setFont:` method on that object.

```
id cell = [mycolumn dataCell];
[cell setFont: [NSFont fontWithName: @"Geneva" size:51.0] ];
```

Comment: I've updated my question. I don't have IBOutlets so I need to iterate through the columns (which are changing)

Answer (score 0):

What if you set an ivar in the method that creates your cells so that the font size is different, then do [tableView reloadData]?

Comment: Mhm, I'm actually creating it once ([listTableView addTableColumn:newColumn];), than the values are binded so there is no such method invoked when I reload the data